What should I pay attention to when traveling with a travel adapter and a foreign power strip?
Where I live, we use 220–240V to power our electronics. I have a 2200W hair dryer that draws up to 10A and a 100W charger that uses up to 0.5A. For the US (110–120V), the current draw would double (20A for the hair dryer and 1A for the charger).
I'm planning to travel with a power strip connected to a universal travel adapter to avoid needing multiple local adapters. My travel adapter is rated for 7 amps, while each outlet on the power strip is rated for 16 amps at 250V.

What limits how much I can safely connect to the power strip: Total watts or something else?
For the travel adapter, do I add together the currents of each device or take their maximum?
If I travel to the US, how can a standard 15A outlet handle a 2200W hair dryer?


Is your hair drier actually dual-voltage?

USA uses different AC frequencies so you can't use it there for that reason alone.

@Transistor It is! All of the devices I travel with are.

How exactly is this an electrical engineering question? Are you designing a hairdryer?

@Lundin Do you think I should post this question elsewhere?

I don't know, there's too little info to tell. Questions about electronics design, component choices, EMC and CE/FCC markings: https://electronics.stackexchange.com. Electrician questions about mains voltage installations: https://diy.stackexchange.com/ Questions about travel adapter products: https://travel.stackexchange.com/

If you ask here please at the very least find some label or manual of the product where it states voltage ratings etc?

@Lundin Well, the question needn't have concerned travel - it could have been about building a computer at home, so I don't think that the travel site would be appropriate here. You can't really call these questions related to DIY either. Finally, I think that you should take me at my word when I say that the products are dual voltage. In any case, proving it adds nothing to the value of the question.

Okay I'll take your word for it. Who needs hair anyway :)

Questions on the use of electronics are off topic.

See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/310721/97780

A question that is on the wrong stack and has been answered elsewhere.

@AndrewJackson whether the question is about travelling with a hairdryer or building a computer at home makes no difference. This is a "use of electronic/electrical product/device question" and has nothing to do with electrical/electronic design. It's off-topic. As far as where it would be on-topic - I have no idea. There is not necessarily a Stack for every conceivable question.

The current draw for your hair dryer will not double, because a hair dryer is just a resistive heating element and a small motor. The motor may have difficulty running, and the heating element will draw far less than 10 A at 120 V--making the assumption of constant resistance, you'll get about 5 A for a quarter the nominal power. Unless your hair dryer is designed to work on 120 or 230 V, which would be a very unusual sort of hair dryer. It'd still draw less than 20 A at 120 V though, if properly designed, because the standard north american household outlet is on a 15 A breaker.


What limits how much I can safely connect to the power strip: Total watts or something else?

Total current. That's what causes heating in its wires. The voltage and hence power is largely irrelevant.

For the travel adapter, do I add together the currents of each device or take their maximum?

Add all the currents together.

If I travel to the US, how can a standard 15A outlet handle a 2200W hair dryer?

It can't, or at least, should not. That's why you only see 3 kW kettles in kitchens in Europe, not the US. I'm very doubtful that a 2200 W hairdryer would be designed for dual voltage, and will remain so until you post a picture of its ratings plate.
FWIW, I do own a slightly bizarre small dual voltage travel kettle. It draws 360 Watts at 120 V. The 120/240 switch puts a silicon diode in series with the element, so it draws only 720 W and not 1440 W on 240 V. The resulting 3 A average DC is unlikely to upset district mains distribution, but I'll wager that an inverter would not like to drive it.


Total amps. This mustn't exceed the limit of the power strip or the travel adaptor.
Add the amps together.
It won't. 15 x 120 is only 1800W.

Most hair driers aren't universal voltage. It's unlikely to work well at 120V. Check the rating plate.

Leave your hair dryer at home  or think about it.  (revised)
Hair dryers rectify AC to run DC motors with different tungsten elements for speed control and heat control so your 230V runs only 500W warm at half speed.  (maybe that's all you want)
Meanwhile a 120V dryer on 230V could burn out the motor and pop the breaker with 4 times the power demand at almost twice the voltage.
Chargers are universal voltage. Check the label.
